# Drag item onto specific position within sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two containers that have multiple items inside. The first contains some icons, that represents the elements that can be inserted into the list. The second container is the actual list and the elements are completely different (from the HTML-structure point of view). It's kinda "Drag an item onto the second list to create this content type".

It works fine like this:

```
this.templates.draggable({ revert: true });
this.content.droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // create element for this list
        // prepend item to the list
    }
});
```

The problem is, that I can only prepend or append the element. So it's irrelevant where the user drops it. But actually the new element should be created between the elements where it was dropped.

So I tried this (without the `drop`-callback from above):

```
this.templates.draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '#idofcontainer'
});
```

This works nearly fine, but it clones the icon. So I have no idea how to stop this behavior and create the new element instead.

So, here's a screenshot, to show what I mean: When the icon is dropped, it should revert to the top list and a new "grey container" should be created at the current position.

[image: example]

Comment: do you wanna retun your icon back to its position after added to the list?

Comment: Yeah, it should revert to it's original place, as you can insert as many as you want of it. I also can't just use different styles. It can be that the final HTML-template will have `<a>`-tags for dragging and `<div>`-tags in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your solution:

```
this.templates.draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: 'clone',
    connectToSortable: '#idofcontainer'
    stop: function(event,ui) { $('#idofcontainer>a').replaceWith('<div>' + $(this).text() + '</div>'); }
});
this.content.sortable({ cancel: '#idofcontainer>div' /* to stop moving divs under container */ });
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BerkerYuceer/KZeBq/

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This is excactly what I've tried in my question. :) So this one works, but it clones the element from above. So what you get is a mixture of `a`- and `div`-tags. Basically it should only specify the place where the element that I create manually should be inserted. Hope it's clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, that works pretty nice. Good idea to simply replace the cloned element. Many thanks for your effort.